# Why use atmosphere instead of plain Jersey?

Tags: jersey, atmosphere

I can't find an answer to this on Atmosphere's website or anywhere else. How do I gain by using atmosphere over plain Jersey for RESful services ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets and asynchronous execution. Without Atmosphere you can't do that with Jersey 1.x. Jersey 2 have some sort of async supported, but still no websocket.